# Django ModelForm Cannot resolve keyword 'ixRegister' into field

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

So I have a model which I'm using to build a table. Each row of the table will be a replica of the `Register` form hence why I'm using `formsets`.

`Register` is my model with a one to many relationship with `RegisterType`

```
class RegisterType(models.Model):
    ixRegisterType = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    sRegisterType = models.CharField(max_length=50)

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'TRegisterType'

class Register(models.Model):
    ixRegister = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    sRegisterName = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    iStartingAddr = models.IntegerField()
    iEndingAddr = models.IntegerField(blank=True)
    ixRegisterType = models.ForeignKey(RegisterType)
    iOffset = models.IntegerField(blank=True)

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'TRegister'
```

In my forms I have this:

```
 class ModbusRegistersForm(ModelForm):
        class Meta:
            model = Register
            fields = ['sRegisterName','iStartingAddr','iEndingAddr','ixRegisterType','iOffset']
            widgets = {
                    'sRegisterName': TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Register Name','class': 'form-control'}),
                    'iStartingAddr': TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Starting address','class': 'form-control','data-extra': '1'}),
                    'iEndingAddr': TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Ending address','class': 'form-control','data-extra': '1'}),
                    'iOffset': TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Address offset','class': 'form-control','data-extra': '1'}),
                }
```

I did it this way since I need custom html attributes becuase the user is going to be able to add rows to the table

Then in my View I have this:

```
def create_modbus_view(request):
    assert isinstance(request, HttpRequest)

    modbus_device = CreateModbusForm()
    RegisterFormset = modelformset_factory(Register, exclude=('ixRegister',))
    registers = RegisterFormset(queryset=RegisterType.objects.all())

    return render(
        request,
        'app/create_modbus.html',
        context_instance = RequestContext(request,
        {
            'title':'Create Modbus Device',
            'tag': 'create_modbus',
            'modbus_device': modbus_device,
            'registers': registers
        })
    )
```

but when I run this I get the exception: `Cannot resolve keyword 'ixRegister' into field. Choices are: ixRegisterType, register, sRegisterType`

```
<tbody>
    <tr id='addr_1'>
        <td>1
        </td>
        {% for field in registers.form %}
            <td>
                {{field}}
            </td>
        {% endfor %}
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

Did it not exclude `ixRegister`? Also is this the correct way to create a model formset? What I'm trying to do is display each form with all its fields along with my `ixRegisterType` as html select and populated with all the options from the RegisterType table

**EDIT**: stacktrace

```
Environment:


Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://localhost:54738/create_modbus

Django Version: 1.8.4
Python Version: 2.7.10
Installed Applications:
('django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.sites',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'app',
 'pymodbus')
Installed Middleware:
('django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware')


Template error:
In template C:\Users\jb.DOM\Desktop\BACnet Modbus\ModbusBACnet\BACnetModbus_WebApp\app\templates\app\create_modbus.html, error at line 59
   Cannot resolve keyword 'ixRegister' into field. Choices are: ixRegisterType, register, sRegisterType

Traceback:
File "C:\Users\jb.DOM\Desktop\BACnet Modbus\ModbusBACnet\BACnetModbus_WebApp\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in get_response
  132.                     response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "C:\Users\jb.DOM\Desktop\BACnet Modbus\ModbusBACnet\BACnetModbus_WebApp\app\views.py" in create_modbus_view
  73.             'register_forms': register_forms
File "C:\Users\jb.DOM\Desktop\BACnet Modbus\ModbusBACnet\BACnetModbus_WebApp\env\lib\site-packages\django\shortcuts.py" in render
  89.             using=using)
File "C:\Users\jb.DOM\Desktop\BACnet Modbus\ModbusBACnet\BACnetModbus_WebApp\env\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader.py" in render_to_string
  115.                         template_name, context, context_instance, dirs, dictionary)
File "C:\Users\jb.DOM\Desktop\BACnet Modbus\ModbusBACnet\BACnetModbus_WebApp\env\lib\site-packages\django\template\engine.py" in render_to_string
  217.             return t.render(context_instance)
File "C:\Users\jb.DOM\Desktop\BACnet Modbus\ModbusBACnet\BACnetModbus_WebApp\env\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in render
  209.                     return self._render(context)
File "C:\Users\jb.DOM\Desktop\BACnet Modbus\ModbusBACnet\BACnetModbus_WebApp\env\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in _render
  201.         return self.nodelist.render(context)
File "C:\Users\jb.DOM\Desktop\BACnet Modbus\ModbusBACnet\BACnetModbus_WebApp\env\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in render
  903.                 bit = self.render_node(node, context)
File "C:\Users\jb.DOM\Desktop\BACnet Modbus\ModbusBACnet\BACnetModbus_WebApp\env\lib\site-packages\django\template\debug.py" in render_node
  79.             return node.render(context)
File "C:\Users\jb.DOM\Desktop\BACnet Modbus\ModbusBACnet\BACnetModbus_WebApp\env\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader_tags.py" in render
  135.         return compiled_parent._render(context)
File "C:\Users\jb.DOM\Desktop\BACnet Modbus\ModbusBACnet\BACnetModbus_WebApp\env\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in _render
  201.         return self.nodelist.render(context)
File "C:\Users\jb.DOM\Desktop\BACnet Modbus\ModbusBACnet\BACnetModbus_WebApp\env\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in render
  903.                 bit = self.render_node(node, context)
File "C:\Users\jb.DOM\Desktop\BACnet Modbus\ModbusBACnet\BACnetModbus_WebApp\env\lib\site-packages\django\template\debug.py" in render_node
  79.             return node.render(context)
File "C:\Users\jb.DOM\Desktop\BACnet Modbus\ModbusBACnet\BACnetModbus_WebApp\env\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader_tags.py" in render
  65.                 result = block.nodelist.render(context)
File "C:\Users\jb.DOM\Desktop\BACnet Modbus\ModbusBACnet\BACnetModbus_WebApp\env\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in render
  903.                 bit = self.render_node(node, context)
File "C:\Users\jb.DOM\Desktop\BACnet Modbus\ModbusBACnet\BACnetModbus_WebApp\env\lib\site-packages\django\template\debug.py" in render_node
  79.             return node.render(context)
File "C:\Users\jb.DOM\Desktop\BACnet Modbus\ModbusBACnet\BACnetModbus_WebApp\env\lib\site-packages\django\template\debug.py" in render
  89.             output = self.filter_expression.resolve(context)
File "C:\Users\jb.DOM\Desktop\BACnet Modbus\ModbusBACnet\BACnetModbus_WebApp\env\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in resolve
  647.                 obj = self.var.resolve(context)
File "C:\Users\jb.DOM\Desktop\BACnet Modbus\ModbusBACnet\BACnetModbus_WebApp\env\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in resolve
  787.             value = self._resolve_lookup(context)
File "C:\Users\jb.DOM\Desktop\BACnet Modbus\ModbusBACnet\BACnetModbus_WebApp\env\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in _resolve_lookup
  817.                     current = current[bit]
File "C:\Users\jb.DOM\Desktop\BACnet Modbus\ModbusBACnet\BACnetModbus_WebApp\env\lib\site-packages\django\forms\formsets.py" in __getitem__
  77.         return self.forms[index]
File "C:\Users\jb.DOM\Desktop\BACnet Modbus\ModbusBACnet\BACnetModbus_WebApp\env\lib\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py" in __get__
  60.         res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
File "C:\Users\jb.DOM\Desktop\BACnet Modbus\ModbusBACnet\BACnetModbus_WebApp\env\lib\site-packages\django\forms\formsets.py" in forms
  142.         forms = [self._construct_form(i) for i in range(self.total_form_count())]
File "C:\Users\jb.DOM\Desktop\BACnet Modbus\ModbusBACnet\BACnetModbus_WebApp\env\lib\site-packages\django\forms\formsets.py" in total_form_count
  117.             initial_forms = self.initial_form_count()
File "C:\Users\jb.DOM\Desktop\BACnet Modbus\ModbusBACnet\BACnetModbus_WebApp\env\lib\site-packages\django\forms\models.py" in initial_form_count
  567.             return len(self.get_queryset())
File "C:\Users\jb.DOM\Desktop\BACnet Modbus\ModbusBACnet\BACnetModbus_WebApp\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py" in __len__
  144.         self._fetch_all()
File "C:\Users\jb.DOM\Desktop\BACnet Modbus\ModbusBACnet\BACnetModbus_WebApp\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py" in _fetch_all
  965.             self._result_cache = list(self.iterator())
File "C:\Users\jb.DOM\Desktop\BACnet Modbus\ModbusBACnet\BACnetModbus_WebApp\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py" in iterator
  238.         results = compiler.execute_sql()
File "C:\Users\jb.DOM\Desktop\BACnet Modbus\ModbusBACnet\BACnetModbus_WebApp\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py" in execute_sql
  829.             sql, params = self.as_sql()
File "C:\Users\jb.DOM\Desktop\BACnet Modbus\ModbusBACnet\BACnetModbus_WebApp\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py" in as_sql
  378.             extra_select, order_by, group_by = self.pre_sql_setup()
File "C:\Users\jb.DOM\Desktop\BACnet Modbus\ModbusBACnet\BACnetModbus_WebApp\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py" in pre_sql_setup
  49.         order_by = self.get_order_by()
File "C:\Users\jb.DOM\Desktop\BACnet Modbus\ModbusBACnet\BACnetModbus_WebApp\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py" in get_order_by
  286.                     field, self.query.get_meta(), default_order=asc))
File "C:\Users\jb.DOM\Desktop\BACnet Modbus\ModbusBACnet\BACnetModbus_WebApp\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py" in find_ordering_name
  558.         field, targets, alias, joins, path, opts = self._setup_joins(pieces, opts, alias)
File "C:\Users\jb.DOM\Desktop\BACnet Modbus\ModbusBACnet\BACnetModbus_WebApp\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py" in _setup_joins
  591.             pieces, opts, alias)
File "C:\Users\jb.DOM\Desktop\BACnet Modbus\ModbusBACnet\BACnetModbus_WebApp\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\query.py" in setup_joins
  1471.             names, opts, allow_many, fail_on_missing=True)
File "C:\Users\jb.DOM\Desktop\BACnet Modbus\ModbusBACnet\BACnetModbus_WebApp\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\query.py" in names_to_path
  1396.                                      "Choices are: %s" % (name, ", ".join(available)))

Exception Type: FieldError at /create_modbus
Exception Value: Cannot resolve keyword 'ixRegister' into field. Choices are: ixRegisterType, register, sRegisterType
```

**EDIT 2**
I must be understanding this wrong, I just changed

```
register_forms = RegisterFormset(queryset=RegisterType.objects.all())
```

to

```
register_forms = RegisterFormset(queryset=Register.objects.all())
```

and it works(drop down still doesn't have values but it renders).

I'm assuming I need to pass it a query of all `Register` instances since I specified that and not a query for all `RegisterType` instances?

Comment: Can you post your full error stack trace please?

Comment: posted the stacktrace

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have to change my form a little bit to get the dropdown to work. I had to create it separately from my widgets and include my db call there:

```
class ModbusRegistersForm(ModelForm):
    ixRegisterType = ModelChoiceField(queryset=RegisterType.objects.all()),
    class Meta:
        model = Register
        fields = ['sRegisterName','iStartingAddr','iEndingAddr','ixRegisterType','iOffset']
        widgets = {
                'sRegisterName': TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Register Name','class': 'form-control', 'data-form': '0'}),
                'iStartingAddr': TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Starting address','class': 'form-control','data-form': '0'}),
                'iEndingAddr': TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Ending address','class': 'form-control','data-form': '0'}),
                'iOffset': TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Address offset','class': 'form-control','data-form': '0'}),
            }
```

then in my view I had to change my formset like so:

```
RegisterFormset = modelformset_factory(Register, form=ModbusRegistersForm)
register_forms = RegisterFormset()
```

I didn't need to pass a queryset since I'm not loading anything from the DB(any previous data that is).